# PHP: Remove useless parts from filename

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have a list of files (in array):

```
C:\Data\..\Users\admin\history.dat
C:\\Users\admin\..\user\history.dat
C:\Users\..\Data\debug.log
```

How can I remove unnecessary parts, so the list will look like this:

```
C:\Users\admin\history.dat
C:\Users\user\history.dat
C:\Data\debug.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`realpath()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function...